# Electron deeplinking not work on dev on macos

Tags: electron, deep-linking

I want to setup a deeplink functionality on my electron app and here's how I set it

```
app.removeAsDefaultProtocolClient('snetwork');

if (isDevelopment && process.platform === 'win32') {
  // Set the path of electron.exe and your app.
  // These two additional parameters are only available on windows.
  // Setting this is required to get this working in dev mode.
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('snetwork', process.execPath, []);
} else {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('snetwork');
}
```

But when running in dev mode on `MacOS`, the protocol is catched, but opens the default `electron` app and not my application.

And on windows I have this error message

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app#important-notes):

> On macOS and Linux, this feature will only work when your app is packaged. It will not work when you're launching it in development from the command-line.

Comment: II have updated the question because even on windows I have the same issue

Comment: @RahmaniSeifElMoulouk Is your app working in the first place? If you run it without the deep link?

Comment: yes it works, the error message occurs with deeplinks

Comment: @RahmaniSeifElMoulouk Maybe you can try to pass something in the third argument of `setAsDefaultProtocolClient` as in the docs: `[path.resolve(process.argv[1])]`